# Неопознанная ошибка (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80004005)

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

Не могу создать web-приложение. Вылетает ошибка. Что только уже не пробовал: переустановка VS, IIS, nuget...

IIS-express 8, VS 2013, Windows 7 x64

Открываю проект (созданный ранее) ASP.NET WEB API - все прекрасно работает, а новый создать не могу - появляется эта ошибка.

Comment: [Visual Studio 2013 > New project > unspecified error (exception from hresult: 0x80004005 (e_fail))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848925/visual-studio-2013-new-project-unspecified-error-exception-from-hresult-0x)

Comment: Печалька... И не заработает, скорее всего. Придётся руками копипастить и править файлы солюшена и проекта, чтобы получился новый.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Заработало.